# How can i copy with cell properties?

Tags: excel, vba

Currently i have the following code. It always needs to be 9 digits. It is possible that in the Vlookup there is a code with 6 digits and the 0 needs to be show before for example 000342345. With the code i currently have he will copy: 342345. How can i get the 0 before shown in the copy?

```
        sheetname.Cells(11, 4).Value = "=VLOOKUP(D10,List!Z:AA,2,FALSE)"
        sheetname.Range("D11").Copy
        sheetname.Range("D11").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Comment: Does it have to *be* 9 digits (which would involve storing the Number as Text), or *display* as 9 digits?  Look up `Format` and / or `Range.NumberFormat`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution 1

Just add the desired number format to your destination cell

```
sheetname.Range("D11").NumberFormat = "000000000"
```

will ensure any number in D11 has 9 digits. This approach will save the number as numeric value in the cell (so you can calculate with it). This is probably the prefered solution.

---

#### Solution 2

Or if you want your number as text (but note you loose the ability to calculate with that "number" then because it is actually text) you can use the `TEXT` formula:

```
sheetname.Cells(11, 4).Formula = "=TEXT(VLOOKUP(D10,List!Z:AA,2,FALSE),""000000000"""
```

Note that you should use `.Formula` to write a formula and not `.Value`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below.

```
    sheetname.Cells(11, 4).Value = "=Right(""000000000"" & VLOOKUP(D10,List!Z:AA,2,FALSE),9)"
    sheetname.Range("D11").Copy
    sheetname.Range("D11").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Append 0 before the value of `VLOOKUP` and select required char in string. You can alsoadjust length of string by checking the `VLOOKUP` value.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're interested in values only, you should avoid passing through formulas and just code:

```
With sheetname.Cells(11, 4)
    .Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(.Offset(-1), Worksheets("List").Range("Z:AA"), 2, False)
    .NumberFormat = "000000000"
End With
```